# Pasar un id a dos consultas

Tags: nodejs, express, mariadb

Estoy utilizando la base de datos MariaDB y realizando una consulta a través de NodeJs y express. En la consulta debo pasar un id, pero este debe de ir en dos partes de la consulta (?), para mayor ilustració este es el código:

```
routes.get('/ajustarOT/:id', (req, res)=>{
req.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
    if(err) return res.send(err);
    connection.query(`
    SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
    INNER JOIN potentialclients ON potentialclients.id_potentialclients = developmentrequest.id_potentialclients
    INNER JOIN users ON potentialclients.id_user = users.id
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
    WHERE users.id =?
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
    INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id_clients = developmentrequest.id_clients
    INNER JOIN users ON clients.id_user = users.id
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
    WHERE users.id =?`, [req.params.id], (err, rows)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        res.json(rows);
    });
})
})
```

No he podido saber como pasar el id para que sea tomado en ambas consultas.

Quien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

ya probaste definir una variable para el valor de `id` y luego **concatenar** esa variable en tu consulta?

```
var id_var   
 routes.get('/ajustarOT/:id', (req, res)=>{
    req.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        connection.query(`
        SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
        INNER JOIN potentialclients ON potentialclients.id_potentialclients = developmentrequest.id_potentialclients
        INNER JOIN users ON potentialclients.id_user = users.id
        INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
        WHERE users.id = '+id_var+'
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
        INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id_clients = developmentrequest.id_clients
        INNER JOIN users ON clients.id_user = users.id
        INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
        WHERE users.id ='+id_var+'`, [req.params.id], (err, rows)=>{
            if(err) return res.send(err);
            res.json(rows);
        });
    })
    })
```